# 'ajax:success' callback doesnot work

Tags: jquery

When I submit my form, I want get a success when success the form. I'm using [jquery ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)

```
$('#new_invitation').submit(function(e)  {
 var $this = $(this);
 $this.on('ajax:success', function(e) {
  alert ('Success');
 });
});
```

**The alert with Success is not fired :(.**

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how are you doing?  It seems to me that you are not actually submitting your form using AJAX since The submit() function will trigger the normal submission of the form. Can you try this code?

```
$('#new_invitation').live('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //Stops the normal form submission process
  form = $(this);
  data = form.serialize(); //serializes the form data
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON', // JSON, HTML, whatever your API responds to
    url: form.attr('action'), //fetches the URL from the form
    success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
      //Success callback
      alert('success');
    }
  });
});
```

This assuming the '#new_invitation' is the ID of the form tag. I recommend you take a look at the jQuery docs site, they have a wealth of information about AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you the problem was fixed :D. I have to my form this. `$('form[data-method="delete"]').live('ajax:success', function(){});`